# Install Google Drive Sync for Windows using Wine

Tags: wine, cloud, google-drive

Is there a way to install the googledrivesync.exe using Wine? I've tried various alternative clients, but they are somewhat limited, and other guides I've followed are somewhat outdated.

Comment: have you tried: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=28866&iTestingId=80398 ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried, but unfortunately it didn't work :(

Comment: i use grive. https://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/ubuntu-google-drive-client-grive-and-grive-tools give that a shot?

Comment: Unfortunately they do not mantain grive tools anymore, but they developed their own sync client called overGrive.

Comment: Unfortunately OverGrive looks very slick but doesn't work. Every morning it resyncs 1500 files and still fails to download new ones.

Comment: Yes, I've found some issues recently too, now I'm looking at other solutions.

Comment: I wouldn't give up on running it with Wine. I've got it working

Comment: @DavidFraser, can you please elaborate how exactly did you get google drive working on wine ?